# curl -X GET is reaching the server with HTTP/1.1 200 OK but not producing expected output

Tags: curl, api

I am using the below command:

```
curl -X GET  'https://<my_account>.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search'
```

This returns "header" information indicating that that command was successful:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

However, it does not give me the search information.

If I put this in a browser:

```
https://<my_account>.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search
```

It DOES return the information I want.

I've looked at the documentation for the [project-search](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-projects/#api-rest-api-3-project-search-get) API call, with its example for `curl`. I am also trying the `curl` command from an API Testing Tool called Talend API. It converts my browser search into that `curl` command.

I can't understand why the curl command indicates a successful connection and yet does not produce any output to the screen in a similar way to the search command I place in the browser.

Is there another way to do this perhaps, or, something obvious I am missing?

I have reviewed the man pages for curl and tried adding in an output command / file but it doesn't make the output any more verbose.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `curl` command is not passing any parameters to the API - you probably want a POST instead of a GET request.

Comment: Hi @roaima I have seen that... I get the same thing, the search returns results in a browser and having followed the same example in the documentation and replicated it, I get nothing back in the curl window in terms of results.

Comment: I don't have an Atlassian account so I don't think I can help you further

Comment: How are you passing your authentication credentials to Atlassian with `curl`? Have you previously logged in (by accessing some login API endpoint) and saved a cookie?

Comment: @Kusalananda this API call _appears_ to allow anonymous access to public resources, but without a valid `<my_account>.atlassian.net` I can't help them by testing further

Comment: @roaima Then it's just a pity that there's no way for us to test this (no real URL in the question) unless we sign up with Atlassian and test with our own accounts, which I'm not going to do for this.

Comment: @roaima that was it, I wasn't using an api token assuming that I would login automatically - so dumb! (It did not give any error though!) Ugh. So Sorry and thank you to you and Kusalananda. Please add an answer vs comment so I can close as answered. :-)